# What do sushi bars do with left overs at the end of the day?

Tags: fish, sushi, restaurant

Just walked past a sushi bar in Bangkok, 20 minutes before closing, no customers but still lots of plates going around on the conveyor belt... so that got me wondering - what do they do with those leftovers?

Considering most of them contain raw fish I'd assume (and hope!) that they don't reuse them... but it's a lot of wasted food.

Comment: I'd assume the same as other restaurants. It's just more visible, as one usually doesn't see the half-full pots at the end of a day in regular restaurants.

Comment: So what do other restaurants do? Leftover boiled potatoes, sauces and other stuff can be used the next day or given to a soup kitchen, but I would guess that raw fish is a whole other thing..? Also, the sushi dishes are fully prepared dishes, whereas normal restaurants would mainly have ingredients (potatoes, sauce) left over? I mean it seems quite unnecessary to carefully prepare all those plates of sushi just to throw them away 45 minutes later...

Comment: The staff eats it all I would have thought.

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 My initial thought as well - they might eat some of it but there is no way they cold eat it all, there were a lot of plates and not a lot of staff (it's quite a small place)... and every night? They'll get really tired of sushi after two weeks :)

Comment: @BadCash.  well at least they will be getting sufficient omega 3 and vit b12! Any chance you could just go in and ask?

Comment: I worked in a sushi bar. Whatever couldn't be put back in cooling, we ate. You develop an appetite after a 10h shift.

Comment: @henning Great to get some first hand account on what goes on in the kitchen :) I'm curious though - if I were the owner of a sushi bar, I would consider solving this "problem" by having a 50% discount for the last 30 minutes (and of course closing the kitchen so no new dishes would me made in that time). I would think that would attract a crowd looking to score cheap late night takeaway :) Also, the particular restaurant that originally got me thinking about this is located in a mall, right next to a food court that is usually busy until closing, so no shortage of hungry people nearby...

Comment: @BadCash good idea. We used to give some samples with the last orders, which at least might improve our standing with customers.

Answer (score 8):

At the sushi belt restaurant I worked at the cut rolls are taken off the conveyor at closing time and the remaining staff takes home whatever is wanted, in the morning the leftovers are disposed of.

Answer (score 0):

Thailand many places have a closing time.  After took of the counter. The help gets what they want. The rest goes to the food truck that comes around.  Has about 6 55 gal. drums in the back. Soup goes in one, bread & noodles another & such. That is took to the poor areas & some have it for breakfast at a Government food line. In some city;s. Think Bangkok is that way. The truck comes early morning.  Philippines in many city's a person may be a kick back. Has a right to dumpster dive. Then resale the 2nd hand food in the slums. In Asia you will find in many places that a certain person has rights to collect all scrap paper from dumpsters. Another food, & such. Little goes to waste in Asia. Your starting to see a end to this at the bigger Malls were they have bailers & such for paper today bail there own & sell it as scrap.

Comment: Are you talking about sushi with raw fish? You mention soup, bread, and noodles - doesn't exactly sound like it.

Comment: What does collecting scrap paper from dumpsters or bailing and selling scrap paper have to do with the question?